# How to set username and password to microsoft access database

Tags: php, ms-access, iis

I used to host my localhost websites data in mysql database. because, mysql comes with an application, i directly open it and i can set/change username and password for databases. Today I tried (for the first time) to use ms access database, and i cannot start because, i do not know where i can set username & password. I search in google, but it is still unclear to me.
I use IIS in windows 10 with odbc drivers installed.

```
    try{
$conn = new PDO("localhost; dbname=global", "usernam",
 "password", $pdo_options);
} catch(PDOException $e){
die($e -> getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Modern versions of Access only support a Database level password (under the File > Encryption) menu. I would not use Access for table level access as it is not supported. Is SQL Express an option for you?

Comment: Thank. I opted for SQL express and it works fine